# Regex to detect one of several strings

Tags: regex

I've got a list of email addresses belonging to several domains. I'd like a regex that will match addresses belonging to three specific domains (for this example: foo, bar, & baz)

So these would match:

1. a@foo
2. a@bar
3. b@baz

This would not:

1. a@fnord

Ideally, these would not match either (though it's not critical for this particular problem):

1. a@foobar
2. b@foofoo

Abstracting the problem a bit: I want to match a string that contains at least one of a given list of substrings.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Use the pipe symbol to indicate "or":

```
/a@(foo|bar|baz)\b/
```

If you don't want the capture-group, use the non-capturing grouping symbol:

```
/a@(?:foo|bar|baz)\b/
```

(Of course I'm assuming "`a`" is OK for the front of the email address!  You should replace that with a suitable regex.)

Comment: this misses the current data posted and has no references or explanations.

Comment: umm, I don't think I missed anything.  My regex matches the first list but not the next two lists, and instructs how to do "or" generally in regular expressions, which answers the last part.

Comment: Agreed; I think it explained it just fine

Comment: You just saved me from losing 12-16 more strands of hair. My ebbing scalp thanks you, sir!

Answer (score 21):

```
^(a|b)@(foo|bar|baz)$
```

if you have this strongly defined a list. The start and end character will only search for those three strings.

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
/@(foo|bar|baz)\.?$/i
```

Note the differences from other answers:

- `\.?` - matching 0 or 1 dots, in case the domains in the e-mail address are "fully qualified"
- `$` - to indicate that the string *must* end with this sequence,
- `/i` - to make the test case insensitive.

Note, this assumes that each e-mail address is on a line on its own.

If the string being matched could be anywhere in the string, then drop the `$`, and replace it with `\s+` (which matches one or more white space characters)

Comment: I would think the forcing it to end is overkill.

Comment: how so?  if you don't do that it'll match a@foosnoz

Comment: enforcing the '.' is good, but there is no email address like a@foo is has to be like @foo.com.tw

Comment: yes, of course it does (hint - I do DNS for a living).  These are just the OPs example domains.

Comment: +1 for atleast thinking it thru and not just dropping something and leaving.

Comment: You've got a bug there — this will match "bar@foo" and "bar@foo.", but not "bar@foo.com". I think you meant "/@(foo|bar|baz)(?:\.|$)/i".

Comment: no, that's what I meant - I've taken "foo" to mean any whole domain name, e.g. "example.com", not the exact literal "foo"

Answer (score 2):

should be more generic, the a shouldn't count, although the @ should.

```
/@(foo|bar|baz)(?:\W|$)/
```

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is a good reference on regex.

edit: change ending to allow end of pattern or word break. now assuming foo/bar/baz are full domain names.

Comment: actually, the '.' ending is optional (hence why mine is followed by a ?)

Comment: that is debatable, until he clarifies if foo === 'google.com' or === 'google'.

Comment: I've taken 'foo' to be a complete domain name, not just a prefix.

Comment: could use the more generic (?:\W|$)

Answer (score 1):

If the previous (and logical) answers about '|' don't suit you, have a look at

http://metacpan.org/pod/Regex::PreSuf

module description : create regular expressions from word lists

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex to find whether a string contains at least one of a given list of substrings. In Python:

```
def contain(string_, substrings):
    return any(s in string_ for s in substrings)
```

The above is slow for a large `string_` and many substrings. [GNU fgrep](http://directory.fsf.org/project/grep/) can efficiently search for multiple patterns at the same time.

#### Using regex

```
import re

def contain(string_, substrings):
    regex = '|'.join("(?:%s)" % re.escape(s) for s in substrings)
    return re.search(regex, string_) is not None
```

#### Related

- [Multiple Skip Multiple Pattern Matching Algorithm (MSMPMA)](http://www.iaeng.org/IJCS/issues_v34/issue_2/IJCS_34_2_03.pdf) [pdf]

Comment: Nope, this wont work.  Because you will get false positives with the 'a@foobar' 'b@foofoo'

Comment: @Harry: Did you read the question and my answer? My code doesn't search for domains it answers the 2nd part of the question:  "I want to match a string that contains at least one of a given list of substrings."

Answer (score 0):

Ok I know you asked for a regex answer.
But have you considered just splitting the string with the '@' char
taking the second array value (the domain)
and doing a simple match test

```
if (splitString[1] == "foo" && splitString[1] == "bar" && splitString[1] == "baz")
{
   //Do Something!
}
```

Seems to me that RegEx is overkill.  Of course my assumption is that your case is really as simple as you have listed.

Comment: The reason I wanted a regex is that I could then parse my data without having to write a whole program to do it; I just dropped data & regex into RegexBuddy in the space of 30 seconds.

Comment: Well my answer works for your question, might not suit your particular case, but the beauty of stackoverflow is that it might help someone else