# Regex to parse all words in a line that follows one of five specific prefixes

Tags: php, regex, string

Consider

```
$email = "Name: John Smith \n
          Phone: 1-888-555-5555
          ...";
```

Suppose I have the code above, and I need to filter the line after the word "Name: ". I have been doing:

```
if (preg_match("/Name:*? (.*)/m", $email, $g) === 1){
    echo $g[1]."\n"; //John Smith
}
```

What is a way to write the regex statement if the string didn't explicitly start with the word "Name: ", but one of 5 variations of it? Here are the five different formats I am working with:

- Name:
- Full Name:
- F. Name:
- First/Last Name:
- Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with several different possible patterns.

This is the [php code to demonstrate your pattern implementation](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/813edc754f14655cb29c9639e1bc33248bd8a1ac)

```
$email='Name: John Smith
        Phone: 1-888-555-5555
        ...';

if(preg_match('/Name[:.] \K[^\r\n]*/',$email,$g)){
    echo $g[0]; //John Smith
}

echo "\n\n---\n\n";

$mult='Name: John Smith
        Phone: 1-888-555-5555
        ...
        Name. Jane Smith
        Phone: 1-888-555-5556
        ...
        First/Last Name: Joe Smith
        Phone: 1-888-555-5557
        ...
';

var_export(preg_match_all('/Name[:.] \K[^\r\n]*/',$mult,$g)?$g[0]:'fail');
```

Pattern #1: (more lenient)  `/Name[:.] \K[^\r\n]*/` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KFgFH2/1)

Pattern #2: (more literal) `~(?:Name.|(?:F(?:. |ull |irst/Last ))?Name:) \K[^\r\n]*~` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KFgFH2/2)

Some notes:

- `[:.]` means match either of the characters (colon or dot).
- `\K` means "start the fullstring match from this point in the pattern".
- `[^\r\n]*` means match zero or more characters that are not line return or new line characters.
- the delimiter in Pattern #2 is changed from `/` to `~` so that the slash between `irst` and `Last` doesn't have to be escaped.
- the `m` flag is not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `or string` matching

```
$email = "Name: John Smith \n
          Phone: 1-888-555-5555
          ...";

if (preg_match("/(Name:|Full Name:|F. Name:|First\/Last Name:|Name.) (.*)/m", $email, $g) === 1){
    echo $g[1]."\n"; //John Smith
}
```

Reference

[Regex to detect one of several strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632244/regex-to-detect-one-of-several-strings)

Comment: PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'L' in php shell code on line 1

Comment: the /L of the last name should be escape as \/Last Name