# Split string by first delimiter found

Tags: javascript

I have a string with multiple delimiters and I wanted to split it by the first delimiter found. I couldn't find any method to do this every method I tried will return either all the char found after the last delimiter or the char between the first 2 delimiters found. How can I get all char after the first delimiter? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
x = 'aa-bb-cc-dd'
console.log(x.split('-')[1]) // returns bb expected bb-cc-dd

console.log(x.split('-').pop()) // returns dd expected bb-cc-dd

console.log(x.split('-')[1].pop()) // something like this but obviously this wont work
```

Comment: You'll want to use a regex that includes a list of your possible delimiters. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632244/regex-to-detect-one-of-several-strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String#indexOf` with `String#slice` like this:

```js
x = 'aa-bb-cc-dd'
console.log(x.slice(x.indexOf('-')+1)) // returns bb-cc-dd
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using slice instead of split and then create a function which will return the expected value like this?

```js
function splitting (str) {
    return str.slice(str.indexOf('-') + 1)
}

const r1 = splitting('aa-bb-cc-dd') // bb-cc-dd
const r2 = splitting(r1) // cc-dd
const r3 = splitting(r2) // dd

console.log(r1)
console.log(r2)
console.log(r3)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way :

```js
x = 'aa-bb-cc-dd'
function splitOnFirstDelimiter (str, del) {
  const index = str.indexOf(del);
  return index < 0 ? str : str.slice(index + del.length);
}
console.log(splitOnFirstDelimiter(x, '-'))
```

Comment: does this bring any difference in runtime from the other answers?

Comment: You don't have to check that `index > 0`.  `String#slice` will work just fine with `-1` as its starting index.

Comment: @Olian04 You are right, thanks a lot mate, cheers :)

Comment: @seriously no , but it allows you to put other delimiters (for example --) , cheers mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't "split" the string: use a Regex to match what you want (or don't want):

```js
/^([^-]*)-?(.*)$/.exec( "aa-bb-cc-dd" )?.[2]
```

Which returns the expected result (`bb-cc-dd`) (or the entire string if no separator was found). And...

```js
/^([^-]*)-?(.*)$/.exec( "aa-bb-cc-dd" )?.[1]
```

gives you the first group (`aa`)

Answer (score 0):

May be too late, but :

```js
var x = "aa-bb-cc-dd";
console.log(
  x.split("-").filter((e, i) => {
    return i != 0;
  }).join("-")
); // returns expected bb-cc-dd
```